# Expecting PreconditionError but got NullPointerException

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception, contract

I have a class Natural with a precondition before the constructor method (notice the requires).

```
public class Natural {
private int data;

@Requires("n != null")
public Natural(Natural n) {
    this(n.data);
 }
}
```

This is the test for that Precondition. It tests the constructor for a null input.

```
@Test(expected = PreconditionError.class)
public void testConstructorWrong2() {
    Natural n = new Natural(null);
}
```

The test should pass, because this test expects a violation of the Precondition. But I am getting NullPonterException instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the [Cofoja](https://github.com/nhatminhle/cofoja#constructors) page:

> However, a very important distinction is that constructor preconditions are checked after any call to a parent constructor. This is due to super calls being necessarily the first instruction of any constructor call, making it impossible to insert precondition checks before them. (This is considered a known bug.

The above probably applies to `this` as well as `super`. The `@Requires` condition can only be checked *after* the call to `this(n.data);` because Java won't allow anything to come before it. And so, the call to `n.data` throws a `NullPointerException` before the annotation even has a chance to check the precondition.

If you still want to check the precondition, you will have to remove the call to `this(...)` and initialize the object directly

```
@Requires("n != null")
public Natural(Natural n) {
  this.data = n.data;
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to change any code inside the constructor